# SFML Custom Circle Math not working properly

Tags: c++, math, sfml

Iam making a program to draw out circles with sfml
using the equation

> x^2+y^2=r^2
>   And then rounding

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    unsigned int rad;
    unsigned int centerY;
    unsigned int centerX;
    std::cout << "Radius: ";
    std::cin >> rad;
    std::cout << "CenterX: ";
    std::cin >> centerX;
    std::cout << "CenterY: ";
    std::cin >> centerY;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600,600), "Circle",sf::Style::Close);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        sf::RectangleShape r(sf::Vector2f(1,1));
        r.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
        //Calculate and draw right half
        for(int i = 0; i <= rad; i++)
        {
            int y = round(sqrt((rad*rad)-(i*i)));
            r.setPosition((float) centerX + i,(float) centerY + y);
            window.draw(r);
            r.setPosition((float) centerX + i,(float) centerY - y);
            window.draw(r);
        }
        //Calculate and draw left half
        for(int i = 0; i <= rad; i++)
        {
            int y = round(sqrt((rad*rad)-(i*i)));
            r.setPosition((float) centerX - y,(float) centerY + i);
            window.draw(r);
            r.setPosition((float) centerX - y,(float) centerY - i);
            window.draw(r);
        }
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, its working but i have this problem:[image]

There is a gap emerging and getting bigger and bigger, I know that sfml would automatically round the flaots, but i want to use the round function. And this issue can be Fixed by drawing the quarter circle twice, starting at opposing coordinates, but that doesnt feel right, i want to use this code as a example of the mathematic principle, and if there is no other way, then i would want to understand why

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: On the right half, the problem is you are only drawing a single 1x1 rectangle in each column. That doesn't work if the column needs to span more than 1 row. The left half has the opposite problem.

Comment: thanks, i'll look into that, but why is it this gap getting bigger the bigger the x is?

Comment: because the circle gets more and more vertical

Comment: One possibility is to loop on the angle a, calculate x= R cos(a), y=R sin(a), and then round x and y. The display should become more homogeneous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you get is a result of a naive implementation that is based on a false assumption that you can draw a good approximation of a quarter of a circle using a number of `(x,y)` points such that every point has different `x` (or different `y`).

To show that this assumption is wrong lets consider radius = 50, and two values `x1= 50` and `x2 = 49`. Obviously the matching `y1 = 0`. What about `y2`? If you use naive implementation as you do, you will calculate

```
sqrt(50^2 - 49^2) = sqrt(99) ≈ 9.9
```

So naively `y2 ≈ 9.9` or almost `10`. Buts what is the `x` value for the range of `y`s in `[1,9]`? The answer is that for all those `y`, `x` lies somewhere between `49` and `50`. In other words you really need at least 10 points for `x=49` and `x=50` rather than just two.

You may try to work this around by using some "draw line" instead of a "draw point" method but it is better to use some well-known algorithm to draw circle such as  [Midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) or Bresenham’s algrorithm

Comment: I'll try to come up with a solution, performance-wise is the an issue with my or @Damien s solution

Comment: @WhAtdaArazhul, I'm not sure I get your question. AFAIK Bresenham’s algorithm has good performance. I don't think you can make Damien's algorithm work reliably for arbitrary radius. It should fail in a way similar to yours (but at other places on the circle) when the radius becomes bigger than the number of steps you do over the angle.

Comment: sorry,but i dont get why it is getting more gapped in that pattern, doing the quarters in diffirent orders changes the circle, And why is it possible to be fixed by manipulating with that @SergGr

Comment: @WhAtdaArazhul, I'm still not sure I understand your question. What is "it" and "that" in the "_why it is getting more gapped in that pattern_"? If that's about your code, then the answer is that at one end of the quarter you have many `x`s for the same `y` and at the other - many `y`s for the same `x`. So if you start from the many `x`s end and iterate over `x`, you are quite OK, probably just draw very close points many times. But as you get to the other end, you don't have enough points. In other words at one end the circle is almost the same as vertical line and at the other as horizontal.

Comment: ok, thanks, can you think of efficient way to get all y s for the x? @SergGr

Comment: @WhAtdaArazhul, have you looked at the wiki article I referenced? Or just tried to google "Bresenham’s circle algorithm"  that I mentioned a few times? This is a well solved problem.

Comment: yes, i did but if theres a good enough solution i'd rather do it this way, if there isn't iam gonna have to stick to what i can get  @SergGr

Comment: @WhAtdaArazhul, why you don't find those solutions "good enough"? They are used for years by many libraries

Comment: it's not about being good enough, it about using the pure principle of x^2+y^2 = r^2 @SergGr

Comment: @WhAtdaArazhul Those algorithms work basing exactly on that `x^2+y^2 = r^2` principle. They just don't assume that one point per `x` or one point per `y` will be enough. BTW have you seen standard [CircleShape](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1CircleShape.php)?

Comment: yes i do know the standart, the thing i am asking if theres is another way to that @SergGr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186246/discussion-between-serggr-and-what-da-arazhul).